# Facebook login sdk not working in release app android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, key

I am using `Facebook login` `sdk` for login into my app. While it working in emulator and also works with build `apk` on mobile with Facebook app and without app.

But when i publish app into play store then its not working. I disable or uninstall Facebook app then it works else it doesn't work.

I also change my `Key Hashes` with signed `jks` file(I have `.jks` file instead of `.keystore`). but it doesn't work.

Any idea whats wrong with it.

I download release app form play store.

Comment: Have you made it **Public** from Facebook developer console?

Comment: @WilsonChristian yes....also it show green big dot which means it is public

Comment: any error message displayed on fb login screen?

Comment: @Pavan no....it start loading and then came back to login/signup page

Comment: did you generate the release hash key ? and add it to the panel?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 yes.... with release `.jks` file

Comment: i  just download openssl file and built hash value using it...

Comment: Any solution for this, i am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
 public void Get_hash_key() {
    PackageInfo info;
    try {
        info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.your_packaage_name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
            Log.e("hash key", something);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    }
}
```

call this method in `onCreate()`  with your package name replaced..it will print the hash key..

copy the key and add it to the developer panel. Under App name

**EDIT** in your Build.gradle

```
 release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true   //add this
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

after building the release apk run it on phone and you will be able to see any logcat error regarding the facebook sdk.

Also remember to `debuggable false` when uploading it to play store.

Comment: i tried my package name which is `in.unfurl.activity`  is says expression expected...what to do...should i write in string???

Comment: it says `E/name not found: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: in.unfurl.activity`

Comment: my package name is `package in.unfurl.activity;`

Comment: just add `in.unfurl.activity` like: `info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("in.unfurl.activity", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);`..also check if it the right package name..cause this exception is thrown when...https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.html

Comment: i got hash key....is it for **release** app code or **build** app and i already upload app to play store. is this work with uploaded apk.

Comment: it is for release hask key..and it will work for the uploaded apk also if you do not change the package name...

Comment: did u copy the full key hash including  `=`?

Comment: i think it's your setup problem ...i edited the answer...also did you add privacy policy URL in panel..? it's required

Comment: i am already using this ` buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }`

Comment: just add `debuggable true`

Comment: @Vivek it's not for working..`debuggable true` is for showing any error related to facebook login..debug will help you get a clear picture of the problem/error..

Comment: i think problem is hash key is not properly set..... i got 5 diffent hash key with different method....some are thround cmd

Comment: and i can not build release app when `shrinkResources true`

Comment: `omit` ? how can i do this

Comment: i mean remove it...you do not need that..i also suggest create a new app id and add it to manifest ..see it it works..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141967/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-vivek).